# codeigniter - Message: Undefined variable: ques

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm pretty new to Codeigniter and tried to follow the Query builder however getting an error.

The view window:

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="bs-component">
        <div class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item"><b><font color="white">EXAMBANK DATABASE</b>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item"> <span class="badge">9</span>
              Total Subjects:
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item"> <span class="badge"><?php echo $ques; ?></span>
              Questions In Database:
            </li>
          </div>
      </font>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
function get_total_questions()
{
    $this->load->model('control/Student_model');
    $question = $this->uri->segment(5);
    $this->Student_model->get_all_question($question);
}
```

Model:

```
function get_all_questions()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('questionbank');
    $this->db->where('question', $question);
    $ques = $this->db->count_all_results();
    return $ques->result();
}
```

Any suggestions??

Comment: Use this `$ques = $this->db->count_all_results(); => $query = $this->db->get();`

Comment: Hi @KevalRathi, thanks for this. I tried entering this into the model but got an error? Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

Comment: would you please check with return only $ques instead of $ques->result();

Comment: @Suvashsarker I tried what you mentioned, still undefined variable in view window?

Comment: Where you have pass data to view file

Comment: Pass data to view `$data['ques'];`

Comment: @Michael Rodwell: please see my answer, hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

You need to return  `$ques;` from your model and you need to pass `$question` in your argument

**Model:**

```
function get_all_questions($question)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('questionbank');
    $this->db->where('question', $question);
    $ques = $this->db->count_all_results();
    return $ques;
}
```

You need to load your view and pass your variable to views

**Controller**

```
function get_total_questions()
{
    $this->load->model('control/Student_model');
    $question = $this->uri->segment(5);
    $data['ques']=$this->Student_model->get_all_question($question);
    $this->load->view('student/list',$data)
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `$question = $this->uri->segment(5);`??

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way:

Controller:

```
function get_total_questions()

    {
        $this->load->model('control/Student_model');
        $question = $this->uri->segment(5);
        $data['ques'] = $this->Student_model->get_all_question($question);
        $this->load->view('folder_name/file_name',$data );
    }
```

Model:

```
function get_all_questions($question)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('questionbank');
    $this->db->where('question', $question);
    $ques = $this->db->count_all_results();
    return $ques; //not $ques->result() because $this->db->count_all_results() Produces an integer
}
```

Comment: I've copied your code across, still have the same error:
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: ques

Filename: student/list.php

Line Number: 38

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="list-group-item"> <span class="badge"><?php echo @$ques; ?></span>
              Questions In Database:
            </li>
```